# How to read spesific content from internet page with Android

Tags: android, io

is that possible in Android to go though whatever [link](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-40338220) and get main content from that page(f.e.text) or whatever i want to get? If yes, how i can realize that?

Comment: Could you please explain what it is that you would like to achieve with this? Do you want to show the content, in which case you could use a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), or do you want to get the content and save it somewhere, in which case a library like [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/download) would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple ways to get data from websites.

**First** and maybe the most popular way is parsing RSS feed from webiste. Java and Android are providing couple parsers and ways to parse xml or in this case RSS Feed. You can take a look in this examples:
https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/src/com.example.android.basicsyncadapter/net/FeedParser.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_rss_reader.htm

**Second** way is getting needed informations from API if it is provided from webiste and offten that API will be in JSON format. For example https://openweathermap.org/ will return JSON file filled with informations of weather which you can pares into your app. Also Android and Java are providing couple ways to get informations from JSON format. You can take a look on this one:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

**Third** you can use support library called `Jsoup` for parsing HTML from particular webiste/s. You can find examples how to parse HTML on their offical webiste: https://jsoup.org/

Maybe there is more ways certanly you should look up for them.